# How to execute the same code on each of the radio buttons with the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code has 3 form groups used for Y/N questions with html `radio` buttons.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q1</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q2</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q3</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q3" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q3" value="n">No
</div>

// Jquery code: 
<script>
var x = 0;

$('input[name="q1"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'y') {
    var x = 1;
  }
});


if(x==1){ 
  alert('res');
}
</script>
```

If possible, please ignore my `var` setting try and share the answer on how to execute the same result if any radio button with value="y" is checked.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you are looking for. If you want to execute the same code on each of the radio buttons, you can select them comma separated as `$('input[name="q1"], input[name="q2"], input[name="q3"]').change(function()`

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code doesn't work because at the page load (doc ready) your x is 0. `var x = 0`

```
if(x==1){ 
  alert('res');
}
```

Here is the example on how to run `console.log` if 'yes' is checked on every radio

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'y') {
    console.log('yes');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q1</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q1</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <p>Q1</p>
   <input type="radio" name="q3" value="y">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="q3" value="n">No
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 'y') {
             console.log('yes');
          }
      });
```

$ ('input [type='radio']') select all the input radio and onClick if the value of the input equal 'y' then it is the right answer

Comment: Could you please explain your solution a bit further?

Comment: @SirPeople $ ('input [type='radio']') select all the input radio and onClick if the value of the input equal 'y' or 'yes' then it is the right answer

Comment: Add this explanation to the answer so people can understand your code :D thanks for helping